# jnlp is updating itself even i have define policy prompt-update

Tags: javascript, java, jnlp

I want update popup become on screen If user run existing application, Update prompt should be visible to user. User will confirm then application should be update. But now if i change the jar version, application auto updated without any prompt even i have define policy='prompt-update'.

I am using below jnlp file

**

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.2.40/New" href="index.jnlp">
 <information>
        <title>Safety</title>
        <homepage href="/Safety" />

        <Application-Name>Safety</Application-Name>
        <icon href="Safety.gif"/>
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="Safety.jpeg" width="32" height="32"/>
        <icon kind="shortcut" href="Safety.jpeg" width="48" height="48"/>
        <icon kind="splash" href="index.jpeg"/>
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut online="true">
                <desktop/>
                <menu submenu="Safety Home"/>
        </shortcut>
 </information>
  <update check="always" policy="prompt-update"/>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
     <resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64 amd64">
        <j2se version="1.6+" max-heap-size="2000m"/>
     </resources>
     <resources os="Linux" arch="x86_64 amd64">
        <j2se version="1.6+" max-heap-size="2000m"/>
     </resources>
     <resources>
          <j2se version="1.6+"/>
          <jar href="Safety-maven-1.0.13.jar" />
     </resources>
     <application-desc main-class="in.NewFrame" />
</jnlp>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, according to the Oracle documentation, you should be setting the attribute `check` to `"background"`.

By setting it to `"always"`, it forces an update before the user starts the application.

(However, I am still struggling with this, because OpenWebStart seems to be ignoring that option and downloading in the foreground anyway - this may be dependent on the WebStart implementation; OpenWebStart is a community project).

```
check attribute: The check attribute indicates the preference for when the JNLP Client should check for updates, and can have one of the three values: "always", "timeout", and "background"

A value of "always" means to always check for updates before launching the application.

A value of "timeout" (default) means to check for updates until timeout before launching the application. If the update check is not completed before the timeout, the application is launched, and the update check will continue in the background.

A value of "background" means to launch the application while checking for updates in the background.
```

(See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#update).

You may also want to refer to this standard document (Avoiding Unnecessary Update Checks):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html